# Keep track of GPG keys

Tags: ssh, encryption, gnupg

When running GPG I'm presented with the following screen:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.20; Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

sec  rsa2048/redacted1
     created: 2016-01-22  expires: never       usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa2048/redacted2
     created: 2016-01-22  expires: never       usage: E   
ssb  rsa4096/redacted3
     created: 2022-02-01  expires: 2023-02-01  usage: E   
[ultimate] (1). Daniël van den Berg <myemail@provider.com>
[ultimate] (2)  Daniël van den Berg <myotheremail@gmail.com>
```

Now I know I just generated redacted3, as I just generated an rsa4096 key to use as ssh key for accessing my git server. But... what did I generate redacted2 for again? (I do remember, but won't in half a year. Or knowing myself, 3 days.)

Can I add comments to my subkey that help me tell them apart? What is the recommended approach to keeping them apart? (A csv with IDs and comments?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I know I just generated redacted3, as I just generated an rsa4096 key to use as ssh key for accessing my git server.

Unlikely to work – it has the `E` usage flag, meaning it's an encryption-only key and cannot be used for authentication (which would involve signing, but in GnuPG has a dedicated `A` usage flag). If you generated it for SSH access, delete it and do it again with the correct usage selected.

> But... what did I generate redacted2 for again? (I do remember, but won't in half a year. Or knowing myself, 3 days.)

It was automatically generated alongside redacted1. It too has the `E` usage flag, meaning it's an encryption subkey – GnuPG automatically creates the first subkey, because the primary key (redacted1) is always a signature-only key. You don't need to remember this specifically for your subkey – keep it your general GnuPG notes, because it's the same for every GnuPG key.

(The primary key has to be *capable* of making signatures, as it certifies subkeys and UIDs. In the distant past, it used to be a multi-purpose `SCE` sign/certify/encrypt key, as RSA can do both – however, for a long time there has been a recommendation against mixing signing and encryption with the same RSA key. Therefore the primary key is now only `SC` or sometimes even just `C` usage, and a separate subkey is needed for encryption purposes.)

> Can I add comments to my subkey that help me tell them apart?

No, GnuPG doesn't have that feature.

> What is the recommended approach to keeping them apart? (A csv with IDs and comments?)

In many cases (e.g. backup storage, work vs personal, etc) create whole separate keys, and they will naturally have different UID labels. For example, I have two separate keysets (one for work, one personal), and they have different email addresses.

But generally you shouldn't *have* that many subkeys to lose track of them. For example, for encryption `E` subkeys, it only makes practical sense to have *one* non-revoked, non-expired subkey at a time – so GnuPG would already let you distinguish them through the "expires:" field. (If you can't distinguish which encryption subkey is the real one, neither can people who would send you messages.)

Meanwhile for signing subkeys, it also rarely makes more sense to have more than one of a given type, because they're all associated with the same identity and the same 'trust' in WoT. For example, if your primary key is RSA `SC`, it would make sense to have an ECDSA signing subkey – but not 3 more RSA signing subkeys.

I would say the same goes for authentication subkeys; it's enough to have one such key tied to your main identity, and if you happen to need more SSH keypairs for specific purposes – they can go under new keysets, or even just remain standalone OpenSSH keyfiles instead of being crammed into your GnuPG keyring.

Comment: Already figured it had the wrong usage flags, re-generated it. Makes a lot of sense. One last question, what does WoT mean? (I assume not the video game with tanks.)

Comment: [Web Of Trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust), the whole PGP thing where you sign other people's keys (certify the correctness of their UIDs).